# Xamarin.Forms - Toasts(Banners) - Alerts - in iOS and Android in Background

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I try to show toasts(banners) notification - while application in the background.

I checked background fetch and push notification. I also received push notification when app in foreground.

But when my app in background - I only see how change my badges count - but i don't see notification

This is my code:

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {

            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init ();
            LoadApplication (new App ());


            if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion (8, 0)) {
                var pushSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings.GetSettingsForTypes (
                    UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound,
                    new NSSet ());

                UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterUserNotificationSettings (pushSettings);
                UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotifications ();
            } else {
                UIRemoteNotificationType notificationTypes = UIRemoteNotificationType.Alert | UIRemoteNotificationType.Badge | UIRemoteNotificationType.Sound;
                UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotificationTypes (notificationTypes);
            }
            return base.FinishedLaunching (app, options);
        }
```

and

```
public override void ReceivedRemoteNotification(UIApplication application, NSDictionary userInfo)
        {

            NSDictionary dic = userInfo.ObjectForKey(new NSString("aps")) as NSDictionary;
            var test = (dic[new NSString("test")] as NSString).ToString();
            var alert = new UIAlertView ("Test title", "This is message", null, "Ok", "Button");
            alert.Clicked += (object sender, UIButtonEventArgs e) => {Console.WriteLine(e.ButtonIndex);};
            alert.Show ();
        }
```

So how i say - in foreground all works great but in background I only see the new count of badges.

I also find this plugin:

https://components.xamarin.com/view/alert-center

But I want to understand how to write it without plugin.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok - I solved it !

For developers who will take same problem:

I just don't send ALERT object in aps json to ios.